# Manage orientation landscape and portrait both in a app iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode5, ui-design

According to my client's requirement I want to set Splash Screen orientation in landscape(right) then the orientation will come in portrait.. any idea how can I implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iPhone only has a single splash screen, no matter which orientation it launches in. The iPad on the other hand will display a different splash screen image in portrait and in landscape mode.

If your iPhone interface supports both portrait and landscape then you must decide which way round you'd like to display that splash screen image. As Kanan says, design your landscape image (say in Photoshop), then rotate the canvas so that the image is portrait (but the content is still landscape).

Answer (score 1):

Just rotate your splash image in an external editor so that is gets displayed in a landscape mode.

Just because you perceive it as landscape doesn't mean it's actually not "rotated portrait".

See your Splash Image will look like this:

[image]

Just rotate your image the way you want it to look like...

Comment: it's works definitely.. n before posting that Question i do it.but i m searching for another solution...